Specific term for a "Synonym Phrase"?
Is there a specific term for a pair of phrases where each word technically has the same or similar meaning, but when taken together, has a completely different meaning or implication?
I used Synonym Phrases in the title, but was wondering if there was a better one.
Examples include:

Butt Dial                 vs                Booty Call                 vs                 Bottom Text
Cottage in the Forest                        vs                        Cabin in the Woods
Forgive me Father, for I have sinned             vs            Sorry Daddy, I've been naughty

I'm sure people can provide others.

First and last are hilarious but what are the meanings in your second example?

These are much beloved of compilers of cryptic crosswords. But the New York Times: Guide to solving cryptic clues doesn't list this exact type (clues based on this phenomenon). It involves an extension of the 'double definition' type, applied across phrases. // 'Synonyms' is unhelpful here, as it is applied to strings having essentially  the same overall meaning (at least sometimes): both single words and longer strings.

Your pairs are closer to false friends than to synonyms.

'butt call' is a phone call dialed accidentally on your mobile phone while sitting on it in your back pocket. A 'booty call' is a somewhat different situation.

This sounds like a duplicate but I can't seem to find a relevant answer on ELU. is 'paraphrase' close enough? Is it worth and answer?

@Mitch That's the whole point. butt == booty and dial == call, but butt dial != booty call. I'm not aware of a name for this type of wordplay.

@Barmar Maybe 'pun'?

@Mitch I was thinking about that. But a pun is usually when you use a homonym or homophone in a (usually humorous) way. I don't think it refers to this. And even if it does, it refers to the use of the words, not the words themselves (which are just homonyms, homophones, etc.).

@dubious, that one isn't as direct at the others, more about how one sounds more romantic than the other

@Barmar - exactly! I was mainly curious if there was a specific term for these.

An example of a crossword clue showing essentially the reverse phenomenon (two totally different expressions that have the same meaning): << London landlords writ large? (7,7) >>. The question mark shows that one of the 'definitions' in this double-definition clue is decidedly left-field. The clue itself displays the double definition. //// Surely examples 2 and 3 above are paraphrases rather than actual examples?

Booty in this context means sexual intercourse (meaning 2), not buttocks (meaning 1).

@StuartF That's the point. These examples depend on the words having both synonymous and non-synonymous meanings, and each phrase uses a different sense. The question is whether there's a name for this pairing. It's also similar to calling "jumbo shrimp" an oxymoron -- while "shrimp" can mean "small", in this case it's just a name for an animal.

A genuine example in a crossword clue: << Angry compiler might be barking but is child-friendly (3,6) >> The answer 'Red setter' corresponds to the phrase 'angry compiler' in the specified way. // A related clue involves 'carnation' not being directly connected to 'motor race', but 'carnation' is a single orthographic word.

Another example is 'warmonger' ≠ 'scrap dealer', but one has to use a definition of 'phrase' that includes single words.

Punning scesis onamaton.
That said, the definition of this charming Greek term is:
Scesis Onomaton

Scesis Onomaton emphasizes an idea by expressing it in a string of
generally synonymous phrases or statements. While it should be used
carefully, this deliberate and obvious restatement can be quite
effective:
We succeeded, we were victorious, we accomplished the feat! Ah sinful
nation, a people laden with iniquity, a seed of evildoers, children
that deal corruptly. --Isaiah 1:4 But there is one thing these
glassy-eyed idealists forget: such a scheme would be extremely costly,
horrendously expensive, and require a ton of money. Wendy lay there,
motionless in a peaceful slumber, very still in the arms of sleep. May
God arise, may his enemies be scattered, may his foes flee before him.
--Psalm 68:1 (NIV)

course notes 

Sc[h]esis Onomaton (skee'-sis-ah-no-maw-ton): Figure of repetition in
which a set of two or more different words having the same (or very
nearly the same) meaning occurs within the same sentence; a successive
series of words or phrases whose meanings are generally equivalent.
Ex: "America is all about opportunity.  That's why my parents came to
America more than 40 years ago. And that's why most of your parents
came here generations ago in search of an opportunity, a chance, a
fair shake."
-- Bobby Jindal, Second Gubernatorial Inaugural Address
American Rhetoric



A series of successive, synonymous expressions.

A man faithful in friendship, prudent in counsels, virtuous in
conversation, gentle in communication, learned in all liberal
sciences, eloquent in utterance, comely in gesture, an enemy to
naughtiness, and a lover of all virtue and godliness. —Peacham
rhetoric.byu.edu

This is a poetic device.

No. This is a list of synonymous phrases; OP asks for phrases whose components are synonyms but whose meaning as compounds / collocations differ. AB vs A'B' where AB means C but A'B' means D. Only OP's first example is actually what the question asks about.

@EdwinAshworth But this is more interesting and educational. Also, my answer does fit with the title, doesn't it?

@Lambie Got something new to learn today. Thanks, but I'm afraid this doesn't answer the question.

If you're deliberately changing OP's obvious intention, I'll have to flag. Open a different question. .... NO, don't ... it's been covered here before, including an answer by yourself.

@EdwinAshworth Such a high horse. Deliberately changing the intention, indeed. I am reading the title of the question very deliberately.

OP concedes it might not be accurate, and I pointed this out earlier. You're choosing a misreading leading to a duplicate.

@EdwinAshworth I really wonder why you and one of your countrymen deliberately omit the the determiner for the word OP. It is most odd.

@Lambie I think I do that sometimes, too. "OP" acts like a name or pronoun. And comments tend to be terse, so OK to omit unnecessary words.

@Barmar Spot on.

@Barmar I'm not asking for the grammar of it; I think I can suss that out for myself. It's like people who say CIA to start a sentence, without the, which, by the way, a lot of texts and people, etc. do use. But it sounds funny to me.

@Lambie I agree, that one sounds funny to me, too. OP, less so. Maybe because I also think of it as referring to OPs as a generic class, even though we're actually discussing the OP of the current question.
